# Compile-time constructor switch in C++

Tags: c++, switch-statement, initializer-list

Is there some sort of compile-time `switch` statement that I can use to pass parameters to a constructor for a member variable? Right now, I have a controller (in the control systems sense, not the MVC sense) that I need to be able to configure its operating frequency at compile time and a filter whose parameters depend on the selected frequency. Here is a skeleton of how I've implemented it:

```
#include <cstdint>

class Filter {
    public:
        Filter(float p1, float p2) : p1(p1), p2{p2} {}

    private:
        float const p1;
        float const p2;
};

class Controller {
    public:
        Controller(void) {}

    private:
        static constexpr uint32_t frequency = 200U;

        Filter filter{frequency == 400U ? 3.0f :    // p1
                      frequency == 200U ? 1.0f :
                      frequency == 50U ? 0.55f : 0f,
                      frequency == 400U ? 2.0f :    // p2
                      frequency == 200U ? 9.0f :
                      frequency == 50U ? 37.1f : 0f,

        };

    static_assert(frequency == 400U || frequency == 200U || frequency == 50U, "Invalid frequency");
};
```

This is obviously very difficult to maintain for large numbers of frequencies, even for only two filter parameters (the real software has more). Every time I need to add support for a new frequency, I need to add code to `n` points in the code, where `n` is the number of parameters for the filter. What I would like is something like this:

```
Filter filter = frequency == 400U ? {3.0f, 2.0f} :
                frequency == 200U ? {1.0f, 9.0f} :
                frequency == 50U ? {0.55f, 37.1f} :
                {0.0f, 0.0f};
```

Or, in my wilder dreams:

```
Filter filter = static_switch_map(frequency) {
            400U: {3.0f, 2.0f},
            200U: {1.0f, 9.0f},
            50U: {0.55f, 37.1f},
        };
```

The parameters for the filter are not formulaically determined and thus cannot be written as part of an expression. Some additional notes:

- I am using c++14 extensions in `clang` and GNU C++.
- I am open to using a higher c++ extension and compiler extensions specific to GNU C++, though c++14 in both `clang` and GNU C++ preferred. `clang`-only solutions are no good to me.
- This is for use in an embedded environment; a run-time solution using `switch` plus `new` plus pointers is unacceptable because of the indirection performance hit, binary file bloat, and the un-safeness of memory allocation in the embedded environment.
- The `Filter` class may be instantiated multiple times.
- Solutions involving templates are okay; I'm only using `float`s right now because I'm porting someone's Matlab code, but I will eventually switch to fixed-point math.

Other solutions I have considered include:

- Conditional compilation using macros and `define` (the `frequency` variable I'm using in the real code is a custom data type, so I'd need to use `define` and a C++ variable that have similar roles; I don't like the idea of having frequency defined in two locations -- that's going to lead to maintenance problems down the road).
- Rewriting variables using a custom preprocessor during the build process. Too magical and will likely become a gotcha to someone in the future.
- Enums. I haven't ruled these out, but I can't think of how to use them in a way that would improve the code without the abilities of Java enums and/or a Python-like `*args` expansion. Admittedly, I've only been writing C++ for about four months (non-consecutively) and only had a solid year of experience with C before that, so there's a good chance I'm missing something, syntax-wise.
- Separate include file to contain the magic; in my project, all automatically generated files have a separate extension, so this works. However, I prefer to have simpler build scripts and keep as much of the logic in the C++ code as possible.

Comment: May be a `constexpr` helper function with a `switch` inside.

Comment: Will you have different `Filter` instances with different values passed to it? Then you probably don't have much choice, and the current solution (or variants thereof, for example saving each value in a `constexpr` variable) is probably the only viable solution.

Comment: Write a constexpr function returning a tuple of parameters for the constructor.

Comment: @user0042 Not sure how to do that without pointers/new, syntactically. Any pointers (no pun intended)? Thanks!

Comment: Returning a [tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) was mentioned. Or maybe a [pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)?

Comment: @n.m., I didn't know you could return a tuple of parameters in C++. Will search. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds to me like you are looking for [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) from C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your switch in a factory method and make your constructor private, so that you are forced to use that method.
This way you'll have only one point to update in your code in future:

```
struct Filter {
    static Filter create(int freq) {
        switch(freq) {
        case 0: return { 0, 1 };
        case 2: return { 3, 7 };
        default: return { 0, 0 };
        }
    }

private:
        Filter(int, int) {}
};

int main() {
    auto filter = Filter::create(2);
    (void)filter;
}
```

If you want to use it also at compile-time, you can slightly change it as it follows (this requires C++14):

```
class Filter {
    constexpr Filter(int i, int j)
        : i{i}, j{j}
    {}

public:
    static constexpr Filter create(int freq) {
        switch(freq) {
        case 0: return { 0, 1 };
        case 2: return { 3, 7 };
        default: return { 0, 0 };
        }
    }

    constexpr int get_i() const { return i; }
    constexpr int get_j() const { return j; }

private:        
    int i;
    int j;
};

int main() {
    constexpr auto filter = Filter::create(2);
    static_assert(filter.get_i() == 3, "!");
}
```

Of course, you can easily add a copy constructor or whatever to your `Filter` class. This is a minimal example to show how the pattern works, nothing more.

---

Another way to define them separately and use each constructor through a call to a factory method is based on delegating constructors:

```
template<int>
struct freq_tag {};

class Filter {
    constexpr Filter(int i, int j)
        : i{i}, j{j}
    {}

    constexpr Filter(freq_tag<0>): Filter{0, 1} {}
    constexpr Filter(freq_tag<2>): Filter{3, 7} {}

    template<int N>
    constexpr Filter(freq_tag<N>): Filter{0, 0} {}

public:
    template<int N>
    constexpr static Filter create() {
        return Filter{freq_tag<N>{}};
    }

    constexpr int get_i() const { return i; }
    constexpr int get_j() const { return j; }

private:
    int i;
    int j;
};

int main() {
    constexpr auto filter = Filter::create<2>();
    static_assert(filter.get_i() == 3, "!");
}
```

It's mainly a matter of taste if compared to the switch-based solution, but for the fact that this one should work also in C++11.

Comment: Obvious caveat (only until C++17) is that `Filter` must be copyable.

Comment: @StoryTeller Fair enough. It's a minimal example anyway. It's not much difficult to add a copy constructor to `Filter`.

Comment: Well, it already is copyable in the MCVE. Just giving a forewarning to anyone who would bother you with " I tried and got this error" because they deleted their copy-c'tor.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ok, good point, let me add a comment at the end of the answer.

Comment: Key was `constexpr`. For my particular use (and in case anyone runs into this), I used approach #2 above, but did not declare the the `Filter` object in my `Controller` class as `constexpr` in case I need to instantiate multiple `Controller`s with different filter parameters. Also, I put the factory method in the `Controller` (since other classes might use the `Filter` differently) and left the constructor for `Filter` as public. `friend` would work, but is not appropriate in my situation where `Filter` is part of a library shared across micros for different PCB layouts. Quite clean. Thanks!